# JSF rendered only if record is null

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

The data shown in the table below is also displayed in my web app. With the exception of the `BOOKINGNO` column, which instead has an `h:commandButton`. The commandButton should only be rendered if the `BOOKINGNO` record is null on the corresponding row.

At the moment, using the code below, the buttons are not rendering.

### table sample

`PLOTNO SITENO  ACCOMNO STARTDATE   ENDDATE     BOOKINGNO
 16     1       10      2014-10-01  2014-10-03  <null>
 21     2       2       2014-09-26  2014-09-29  923291
 22     2       3       2014-10-01  2014-10-03  <null>
 23     2       7       2014-09-26  2014-09-29  457235`

### JSF

```
<h:dataTable> 

    ...

    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton 
            onclick="if (!confirm('Do you want to book this holiday?')) return false"
            value="Book"
            action="#{dealsBean.book(item.plotNo)}"
            rendered="#{dealsBean.bookingNo = null}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
/<h:dataTable>
```

I've tried various different `rendered` arguments but none seem to do what I want.

Am I getting the syntax right?

Comment: Use `rendered="#{empty dealsBean.bookingNo}"` that follows both `null` as well as an empty string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `==` as operator

```
rendered="#{dealsBean.bookingNo == null}"
```